# How to specify values for parent Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to configure Prometheus, which is included in the Gitlab Helm chart according to https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab/blob/master/requirements.yaml

My main issue is how to configure Prometheus, as the following `values.yaml` seems to be ignored:

```
global:
  registry:
    enabled: false
  # Disabling minio still requires to disable gitlab.minio or it will complain about "A valid backups.objectStorage.config.secret is needed"
  minio:
    enabled: false
  ingress:
    configureCertmanager: false
    class: "nginx"
 ...

prometheus:
  install: true
  rbac:
    create: true
  #kubeStateMetrics:
  #  enabled: true
  nodeExporter:
    enabled: true
  #pushgateway:
  #  enabled: true

  server:
    configMapOverrideName: prometheus-config
    configPath: /etc/prometheus/conf/prometheus.yml
    persistentVolume:
      enabled: true
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      mountPath: /etc/prometheus/conf
      # Increase afterwards, this is for my tests
      size: 2Gi

  alertmanager:
    enabled: true
    # Overriding the default configuration with the existing one
    configMapOverrideName: "alertmanager"
    configFileName: config.yml
    persistentVolume:
      enabled: true
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      mountPath: /prometheus
      # Increase afterwards, this is for my tests
      size: 2Gi
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access those values in chart ?
Could you mention the syntax please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checked the link you provided and it seems you are trying to add values into values.yaml of your parent chart, where prometheus is a dependent sub-chart.

Specifying values at parent values.yaml file is done exactly in the same way you provided above.

Values for sub-chart should go into a property named exactly as the sub-chart.

```
parentProp1: value
parentProp2: value
global:
  globalProp1: value
  globalProp2: value
subchart1:
  subchartProp1: value
  subchartProp2: value
```

Now in the above set of values, let's assume there is a `parentchart` and it has a sub-chart named `subchart1`. You need to understand the following points:

- `parentProp1` and `parentProp2` can only be accessed in `parentchart` and not in `subchart1` as `Values.parentProp1` and `Values.parentProp2`
- global properties can be accessed from both parent and subchart1 as `Values.global.globalProp1`
- `subchartProp1` and `subchartProp2` can be accessed as `Values.subchart1.subchartProp1` and `Values.subchart1.subchartProp2` in `parentchart`
- `subchartProp1` and `subchartProp2` can be accessed as `Values.subchartProp1` and `Values.subchartProp2` in `subchart1`

Also please don't forget to use proper syntax of double curly-braces `{{ Values.xyz }}`

I hope it helps. :)